# Reusable function to add a class to element when a user scrolls to it

Tags: jquery, function, scroll

I need to create a function that causes a class to be added to an element when the user scrolls to it. I know the basic idea of making it work, but what I can't get to work is creating the function, and somehow binding it to different elements.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.showIcon = function() {
       var $elID =  this;
       $(window).scroll(function() {
          var height = $(window).height() / 1.25;
          var offset = elID.offset().top - height;
          if ($(window).scrollTop() >= offset) {
            $(this).find(".img-responsive").addClass('show');
          }
        });
      }
    $('#icon-1').showIcon();
    $('#icon-2').showIcon();
    $('#icon-3').showIcon();
});
```

The errors I get are telling me that elID is not defined, so obviously the "this" part at the beginning of the function is not understanding what element I am targeting.

This was the latest version I had, but I've tried a bunch of different ways of targeting the ID of the elements with no luck.

So what I am trying to do is make it so that when a user scrolls to #item-1, #item-2, or #item-3, the function showIcon() is triggered.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

////

Here is an update removing the $elID variable, but it seems to be the $(this) part that doesn't want to target the element I'm trying to get. I don't know how to get the element that the function is getting applied to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.showIcon = function() {

       $(window).scroll(function() {
          var height = $(window).height() / 1.25;
          var offset = $(this).offset().top - height;
          if ($(window).scrollTop() >= offset) {
            $(this).find(".img-responsive").addClass('show');
          }
        });
      }
    $('#icon-1').showIcon();
    $('#icon-2').showIcon();
    $('#icon-3').showIcon();
});
```

Comment: Ok, I'm taking that part out because it doesn't seem to matter. Even if I remove that variable, I still can't seem to target the ID's of the elements. Look for my update.

Comment: I didn't mean take it out, I meant that you had a variable called $elID, and in your function were trying to get elID, which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah and I think really what it comes down to is that I don't know how to target the elements that I am applying the functions to, which is what the $elID is meant to represent. Clearly, using this, and $(this) isn't doing it, so I'm not sure if I'm going about this in completely the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with context - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.fn.showIcon = function() {

   // this here is a jquery object
   var $element =  this; 

   $(window).scroll(function() {

      // this here is the window object
      var $window = $(this);

      var windowHeight = $window.height() / 1.25;
      var offset = $element.offset().top - windowHeight;
      if ($window.scrollTop() >= offset) {
        $element.find(".img-responsive").addClass('show');
      }
    });
  }

  $('#icon-1').showIcon();
  $('#icon-2').showIcon();
  $('#icon-3').showIcon();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P2ptx/

Comment: Excellent. There be the answer.